# How to find the longest string in a TRIE

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I've already implemented a DS Trie by 2 classes: Trie & TrieNode.
I need to write a function that return the longest string in the Trie in O(h).
My TrieNode has a field LinkedList which store the children of every Node.
We still haven't learned about BFS or DFS so I'm trying to think about some creative way to solve it.

I already have a function (A SEPARATE function) that inserting/creating a new Node by a given char:
While building the Trie: create a Node with a field 'maxDepth=0' that indicate what's my current depth. For every new Node that I've created I'll iterate all the way up to his Parent (Every Node already has a pointer to his parent) and so on until I'll reach the root, and increase his parent's depth by 1.
Now I'll create the function that return the longest string by this way: For every Node: Iterate through my children, look for the max integer 'maxDepth' than go down. do that until you reach 'maxDepth==0'. 
For Example my Algorithm will work fine for this string: "aacgace"

```
       root      
       / \
   (2)a   g(0)     
     / 
 (1)c        
   / 
(0)e
```

=> 'ace' is actually the longest. 
But won't work fine for this string: "aacgae"

```
      root      
      /  \
   (2)a   g(0)     
    /  \
 (0)c  (0)e
```

=> is seems like Node 'a' has a child which his child also has a child, but it doesn't true.

In general I'm trying to utilize the first function that create the Trie (Running Time: O(h*c)), so the running time of the second function (that return the longest string) will be has less has I can. O(h)

Comment: That is a rather strange way to use a trie...

Comment: First of all, what are the words in you trie?

Comment: Is that matter?The whole project is to encode a text file using a Trie so the words could be any English alphabet.

Comment: Well then I don't understand how you build your trie at all. I do have a trie implementation, see how I do it. Note that you could have a go at a radix tree as well.

Comment: Couldn't you do a breadth first traversal to get to the deepest node then walk back up to the root from there to get the string?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you really want to do but you can find an example of a trie [here](https://github.com/fge/grappa/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/grappa/matchers/trie).

Basically I go through a builder to create the trie; let's do a quick rundown of how a word is added to the trie:

```
// In TrieBuilder
final TrieNodeBuilder nodeBuilder = new TrieNodeBuilder();

// ...

/**
 * Add one word to the trie
 *
 * @param word the word to add
 * @return this
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException word is empty
 */
public TrieBuilder addWord(@Nonnull final String word)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(word);

    final int length = word.length();

    if (length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("a trie cannot have empty "
            + "strings (use EMPTY instead)");
    nrWords++;
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, length);
    nodeBuilder.addWord(word);
    return this;
}
```

This defers adding the word to a TrieNodeBuilder, which does this:

```
private boolean fullWord = false;

private final Map<Character, TrieNodeBuilder> subnodes
    = new TreeMap<>();

TrieNodeBuilder addWord(final String word)
{
    doAddWord(CharBuffer.wrap(word));
    return this;
}

/**
 * Add a word
 *
 * <p>Here also, a {@link CharBuffer} is used, which changes position as we
 * progress into building the tree, character by character, node by node.
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>If the buffer is "empty" when entering this method, it means a match
 * must be recorded (see {@link #fullWord}).</p>
 *
 * @param buffer the buffer (never null)
 */
private void doAddWord(final CharBuffer buffer)
{
    if (!buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        fullWord = true;
        return;
    }

    final char c = buffer.get();
    TrieNodeBuilder builder = subnodes.get(c);
    if (builder == null) {
        builder = new TrieNodeBuilder();
        subnodes.put(c, builder);
    }
    builder.doAddWord(buffer);
}
```

Let's say we add both "trouble" and "troubling" to the trie; what happens is this:

- the first time, nodes are created for each individual character of "trouble";
- the second time, all nodes until "l" exist; then all nodes are created for "ing".

Now, if we add "troubles", a further node will be created for the "s" after the "e".

The `fullWord` variable tells whether we have a potential full match here; here is the search function:

```
public final class Trie
{
    private final int nrWords;
    private final int maxLength;
    private final TrieNode node;

    // ...

    /**
     * Search for a string into this trie
     *
     * @param needle the string to search
     * @return the length of the match (ie, the string) or -1 if not found
     */
    public int search(final String needle)
    {
        return node.search(needle);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And in `TrieNode` we have:

```
public final class TrieNode
{
    private final boolean fullWord;

    private final char[] nextChars;
    private final TrieNode[] nextNodes;

    // ...

    public int search(final String needle)
    {
        return doSearch(CharBuffer.wrap(needle), fullWord ? 0 : -1, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Core search method
     *
     * <p>This method uses a {@link CharBuffer} to perform searches, and changes
     * this buffer's position as the match progresses. The two other arguments
     * are the depth of the current search (ie the number of nodes visited
     * since root) and the index of the last node where a match was found (ie
     * the last node where {@link #fullWord} was true.</p>
     *
     * @param buffer the charbuffer
     * @param matchedLength the last matched length (-1 if no match yet)
     * @param currentLength the current length walked by the trie
     * @return the length of the match found, -1 otherwise
     */
    private int doSearch(final CharBuffer buffer, final int matchedLength,
        final int currentLength)
    {
        /*
         * Try and see if there is a possible match here; there is if "fullword"
         * is true, in this case the next "matchedLength" argument to a possible
         * child call will be the current length.
         */
        final int nextLength = fullWord ? currentLength : matchedLength;


        /*
         * If there is nothing left in the buffer, we have a match.
         */
        if (!buffer.hasRemaining())
            return nextLength;

        /*
         * OK, there is at least one character remaining, so pick it up and see
         * whether it is in the list of our children...
         */
        final int index = Arrays.binarySearch(nextChars, buffer.get());

        /*
         * If not, we return the last good match; if yes, we call this same
         * method on the matching child node with the (possibly new) matched
         * length as an argument and a depth increased by 1.
         */
        return index < 0
            ? nextLength
            : nextNodes[index].doSearch(buffer, nextLength, currentLength + 1);
    }
}
```

Note how -1 is passed as the "nextLength" argument in the first invocation of `doSearch()`.

Supposing we have a trie with the three words above, here is the sequence of calls for a search of "tr", which fails:

- doSearch("tr", -1, 0) (node is root);
- doSearch("tr", -1, 1) (node is 't');
- doSearch("tr", -1, 2) (node is 'r');
- no next character: return nextLength; nextLength is -1, no match.

Now, if we have "troubles":

- doSearch("troubles", -1, 0) (node is root);
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 1) (node is 't');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 2) (node is 'r');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 3) (node is 'o');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 4) (node is 'u');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 5) (node is 'b');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 6) (node is 'l');
- doSearch("troubles", -1, 7) (node is 'e');
- doSearch("troubles", 7, 8) (fullword was true! node is 's');
- no next character: return nextLength, which is 8; we have a match.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're thinking in the right way - if you want to find the longest string without iterating through the whole tree, you have to store some information while building the tree.
Assume that for node `i`, we store the maximum length in `max_depth[i]` and we remember its child that has the maximum length in `max_child[i]`. So, for each new word that you've inserted into the trie, remember the last node that you've inserted (which is also a new leaf, that represent the last char of your string), do the following:

```
current = last_inserted_leaf
while (current != root):
    if max_depth[parent[current]] < max_depth[current] + 1:
        max_depth[parent[current]] = max_depth[current] + 1
        max_child[parent[current]] = current
    current = parent[current]
```

And now, to output the longest string, just do the following:

```
current = root
while is_not_leaf(current):
    answer += char_of_child[max_child[current]]
    current = max_child[current]
return answer
```

So, the inserting takes `2*n = O(n)` operations, and finding the longest string takes `O(h)`, where `h` is the length of the longest string.

---

However, the described above algorithm takes `O(n)` additional memory, and it is too much. The easiest way is to store somewhere a `max_string`, and each time you add a string to the trie, just compare the length of your `new_string` and the length of the `max_string`, and, if the new length is larger, then assign `max_string = new_string`. It will take less memory and the longest string will be found in just `O(1)`.